# Python giving 'psycopg2.DataError: cannot EXECUTE a null querystring' error for Postgres function exeuction

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am trying to execute the following Postgres function using Python. The 
cur.execute statement basically executes the test_schema.f_cdrivers function.

```
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database = "xxxxx", user = "xxxxx", password = "xxxxx", host = "xxxxxx", port = "9999")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute('''
        SELECT test_schema.f_cdrivers(
        ' abcd.pi_ch_ixns_day_t1 ',
        ' abcd.ChIxnData_t1 ',
        ' abcd.ChIxnDay_t1 ',
        ' abcd.ChIxnMatrixDay_t1' ,
        'day',
        'xy')      
        ;''')
```

However I get the following error in the last line:

File "test.py", line 35, in 
;''')
psycopg2.DataError: cannot EXECUTE a null querystring

I am guessing the last parameter 'xy' getting input as empty in to the function.I tried playing around with the last line, but I am not able to figure out the error. I am able to run other functions with similar setup, but just this alone gives error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the actual Postgres function itself, and nothing to do with Python. One of the table was having no rows and as a result null query error was throwing up.